# Hiding packets, requests, traffic from my PC through Ethernet connected to workplace network

Tags: network, network-scanners, wireshark, ipsec

Before everyone jumps on the bandwagon, as I so often see, of saying you shouldn't do anything on a workplace network that is to be done annonymously on your own home network, I want to know an actual answer...

Can my traffic be encrypted before it hits the router so that no one knows what URLs or IPs I visit??

Technically I don't visit anything bad but I am relatively security conscious and I don't like the idea of anyone viewing my traffic using ettercap, wire shark etc...

So how do I remain anonymous in this regard.. I know vpn will hide my IP but that's after my request flies out of the router, isn't it ?? and I know no-IP will mask my routers IP address coming back in but what can I do for the connection in the back of my PC to the Ethernet network to the router...

Surely it's encryptable somehow so that no one knows what's being surfed from my Ethernet port on the network

Comment: If you use a VPN, all that can be determined is that you're using the VPN. They have no way to know what sites you are visiting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A VPN is a solution to this problem, as is Tor (assuming correct configuration). With both of these methods, it is obvious you are using them, however all of your traffic is encrypted between you and some remote endpoint (VPN server, Tor node, etc.) such that nobody on your local network can see your final destination or data.

Comment: Thanks for the straightforward answers, I didn't realise that vpn protected you at that level.. Cool, any suggestions for a good provider? I found these guys on a forum before and they seem promising with all the usual promises of no logs etc but I can't help feel dubious about a provider based in America https://www.privateinternetaccess.com/pages/buy-vpn/